# Openldap 2.4 within Docker container

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap, slapd

I'm setting up an openldap server (slapd) within a docker container, I just took the latest centos image (tags: latest, centos7, 7, [image here](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/16dab97b0ce72b1db7a2f9b02c76e452cb0a63cb/docker/Dockerfile)

and then I've installed following packages:

- openldap-servers-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
- openldap-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
- openldap-clients-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64
- openldap-devel-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64

and then just started the service with `/usr/sbin/slapd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/`

Then I'm trying to add the domain and root user to ldap configuration using this ldif file (db.ldif)

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=mydomain,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=myadminuser,dc=mydomain,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}blablablabla
```

Then when I run `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif`

It throws me this `ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

I see the port is open 'cause telnet can connect to it and actually doing ldapsearch from another machine works `ldapsearch -h $myserver -p $myport -x`

And response this:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you clarify where the commands are being run? Is `ldapmodify` being run outside the container? Can you also clarify how the container was started (what ports are exposted)? If `ldapmodify` is being run outside the container it would seem that URI `ldapi:///` might need to be adjusted to be the proper host IP address (`ldapi:///` is probably the equivalent of `ldapi://localhost/`).

Comment: I run ldapmodify within the container, port is exposed, I started the container like this:
`docker run -t -d --name ldap1 -p 389 centos_ldap:0.1` (commited an image centos_ldap after installing ldap packages) , I've tried with `ldapi://localhost/` and doesn't works either